Averaged measure in integrations
Consider
\begin{align} 
& F(n,x)\equiv \int_0^x \cdots g (x_5)\int_0^{x_5} ~\int_0^{x_4} g (x_3)~~\int_0^{x_3} ~\int_0^{x_2} g (x_1)~~A(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n
\end{align}
where $g(x)$ is a measure. $A(x)$ is independent of $n$.
To find $F (n,x)$, I wonder if one may write it as
\begin{align} 
F(n,x)=\int_0^{f(x)} \cdots  \gamma (x_5)\int_0^{f(x_5)}  \gamma (x_4)~\int_0^{f(x_4)}\gamma  (x_3)~\int_0^{f(x_3)} \gamma  (x_2)~\int_0^{f(x_2)} \gamma  (x_1)~B(x_1)\,dx_1\cdots dx_n  \ .
\end{align}
Has the related transformations/formulae been discussed in the literature?

do you allow $B$ to depend on $n$?

That's the simpler case, but it mostly remains unclear how to obtain $F(n,x)$.

Take $\gamma(x)\equiv 1$, $f(x)\equiv x$; for given $n$, $g$, $A$, the first expression is some function $F(x)$, which must equal the second expression for some $B$; using the Cauchy formula, we thus have
$$F(x)=\frac{1}{(n-1)!}{\int_{0}^{x}{(x-t)^{n-1}B(t)\,dt}}.$$
This is a linear integral equation for $B$ given $F$, which should be solvable.

This would require knowing $F(n,x)$ first.

Well, I guess the second expression in this post is probably misleading and not useful.. If preferred and possible, I am happy to remove the post.
